# Since when the bullet stuck in the opera floor and where did it come from?

Tags: tenet

In one of the first scenes in Tenet (so not really a spoiler I hope) an inverted gunman fires a bullet into the wooden floor of the opera.
From the non inverted point of view the hole was already there and when the inverted gunman fires, the bullet leaves the hole, the hole disappears and the bullet returns into the gun.

So far, so logical.

But when from our normal non inverted view the hole was already there - since when was it there? When the opera was build they surely didn't build in a wood piece with a bullet in it.

If we switch to the inverted view, the following should happen (I think) :

The bullet stucks in the hole until the oper is "unbuild". The wood piece is brought back to the sawmill where it is combined with other pieces to a tree trunk that contains now the bullet (and the hole). The trunk is brought back to the forest und uncut. The tree ungrows until it is to small to contain the bullet. The bullet falls to the ground, is buried and erodes to dust.

From an uninverted view it would look like the following:

A bullet assembles itself from dust over decades. A tree starts growing exactly in this place. It engulfs the bullet when it grows (mysteriosly cultivating a "bullet hole" around it that looks exactly as if the bullet was fired into a layer of it whithout effecting the layer above). The tree is cutted, sawed and the wood pieces are brougth to the opera building place. The wood piece is build into the opera floor an the worker mysteriously does not notice the hole and replace the wood piece. From then on until present nobody seems to notice the hole or at least takes any actions to "repair" it.

That seems strange. Even more in a later case where the holes are in a glass panel (and the bullets into a concrete wall). Did the workers build in glass panels with holes? And work in bullets into the concrete wall?

So, since when the hole in the floor was there (from ininverted perspective). Did it appear a few hours earlier magically (implying that actions/changes done by inverted people do not "last" but disappear from their point of view, clearly contradicting other events in the movie)?
Or is it according to my above description then the question is why did nobody notice and fix the hole an why did they build in glass panels with holes?

Comment: The hole would have appeared at the moment that the gun (or rather its operator) became inverted, not before.

Comment: So you think it's kind of mutable timeline? But that does not change the "fact" that in the resulting timeline the hole must have "always" been there, rising the mentioned logical problems.

Comment: The only thing I could think of is, that the Tenet people (who actively try to preserve the timeline with information hiding and "help" fulfilling what they already know and not change anything in several other cases) clean it up "later" (=earlier) by removing the bullet and fixing the hole, what from uninverted perspective will look like a man walking backwards who "implants" the bullet and the hole a day before or something like that.

Comment: Logically speaking, since the bullet hole occurred backwards in time it stands to reason that a skilled tradesman turned up a few hours before in order to remove a section of unbroken wood and install a piece of wood into which he's carefully inserted a bullet.

Comment: .ereht derif saw ti ecniS

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed in the film. In short, entropy can run one way or the other, but since the current universe (which is very big) is running one way, and the inverted objects (which are very small) are running the other way, what happens is it that the universe simply takes care of any paradoxes.

> **Neil:** *As they invert the entropy of more and more objects... the two directions of time are becoming more intertwined.*
>
> Makes Tenet gesture
>
> **Neil:** *But because the environments entropy flows in our direction we dominate. They're always swimming upstream. It's what saved your
> life - the inverted explosion was pushing against the environment.*
>
> **TP:** *Pissing in the wind.*
>
> **Neil:** *But the algorithm can change the direction of that wind. It can invert the entropy of the world.*

The reverse is true in the opposite direction, with the bullets *fading into existence* until they're sucked into the gun, thus preventing the logical paradox from occurring.